# Property is not defined .props

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core

I am trying to get shared property [like in this tutorial](http://jackhiston.com/2017/10/12/msbuild-maintenance-made-easy-with-shared-properties/) from .prop file, but running

```
msbuild propsTests2.sln
```

is giving error:

```
  C:\...\propsTests2.csproj(8,58): 
error MSB4066: The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized.
```

My files:

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project=".\common.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="$(AspNetCoreVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**common.props**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AspNetCoreVersion>2.0.0</AspNetCoreVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

file common.props is in the same directory as .csproj file.

I am using VS2017.

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with the property sheet whatsoever: it tells you the PackageReference has no Version attribute, so you cannot set it. The value you want to set it to is irrelevant.

Comment: I think it is not the case, when i will put there a number without using variable everything works fine.